# M1 2020 and M1 2021 different screen scalings on 5k screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, apple-silicon

I've got an 2020 M1 MacBook Pro and a 2021 M1 Pro MacBook Pro (work and private machines) and since I've got a new monitor at home I'm experiencing something strange:
The screen has a resolution of 5120x2160 px and both MacBooks can handle it correctly, but the scaling factors are different.

The 2020 MBP can scale for 3008x1269,
the 2021 MBP can scale for 3840x1620 (which looks better).

[image: 2020 MBP scaling]
[image: 2021 MBP scaling]

Do the MBPs really have different graphics chips where the older one does not support my desired scaling resolution (3840x1620)? Is there a way to set this on the older one as well?

Comment: I see a "Liquid Retina..." on the far top left of your second screen shot, therefore I assume this is a Pro/Max chip instead of the normal M1. However, they both support at least one display 6k@60Hz so this should work the same IMO

Comment: Yes, the newer one is the M1 Pro (I've added it to the description). But as you said I thought it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: How is the monitor interfaced to each one?

Comment: I connect both of them with the same thunderbolt cable.